# send message to Django admin from save method

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to write function in Django models when save object sends a message to Django admin panel I tried to use 'django.contrib.meseseges' but it needs a request and I cant give request to func!

what can I do?!

```
#models.py
class MyClass(models.Model):
   field1 = models.IntigerField()
   field2 = models.IntigerField()

   def my_func(self)
      if my_condition == false:
         messages.warning(request= ??? ,"my message")

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
       self.my_func()
       super().save()
```

Comment: why not send back message from your view? I mean after check condition return some status of your function to your view and decide what to do based on status.

Comment: Because I want to send this message in the admin panel